# Retrying bash command n times and sleeping m seconds in between

Tags: bash

Bash script here.

I want to run a command that will output an integer `0+` (0, 1, 2, 45, 193, etc.). I want to run it at least one time. If I run it the first time, and its output is `0`, then the script can exit. If it is `1+` then I want to keep running the same command over and over until it returns `0`, and then like before, the script can exit. However:

- I only want the command to be retried every 60 seconds; and
- I only want the command retried a maximum of 10 times; after the 10th time if the command is still returning `1+` then I want the script to exit with an error code (`exit 1`, etc.)

My best attempt thus far, inspired from a similar question here on SO:

```
# doSomething() returns 0 or higher
NEXT_WAIT_TIME=0
until [ $NEXT_WAIT_TIME -eq 10 ] || doSomething(); do
  $(( NEXT_WAIT_TIME++ ))
  sleep 60
done
```

However when this runs, it doesn't actually check for comparison of the output for `0` vs. `1+` and it executes 10 times immediately without sleeping in between tries. Can someone sport where I'm going awry? Thanks!

Comment: `sleep 60` surely?

Comment: ahh nice catch, thanks! however the problem still remains: its not evaluating the 0 vs 1+ return from `doSomething()` and its ignoring the `sleep` altogether!

Comment: `doSomething` without trailing parentheses.

Comment: Try pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net

Comment: OK thanks, but... I guess I don't understand where its doing the "_if-doSomething-equals-1-then-retry_" logic. Am I missing something?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

remaining_attemps=10

while (( remaining_attemps-- > 0 ))
do
    [[ $(doSomething) == 0 ]] && exit
    sleep 60
done

exit 1
```

---

**Edit:** Replying to OP comment.

You have a few options for running commands before exiting when `doSomething` outputs `0`

###### 1. Inside the `while` loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

remaining_attemps=10

while (( remaining_attemps-- > 0 ))
do
    if [[ $(doSomething) == 0 ]]
    then
        echo "doSomething = 0"
        exit
    fi
    sleep 60
done

exit 1
```

###### 2. Outside the `while` loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

remaining_attemps=10

while (( remaining_attemps-- > 0 ))
do
    [[ $(doSomething) == 0 ]] && break
    sleep 60
done

(( remaining_attemps >= 0 )) || exit 1

echo "doSomething = 0"
```

Comment: Thanks @Fravadona (and +1)!!! If I wanted to put an `echo` and display a message if `doSomething` is zero, where would I place it before exiting?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup I Updated my answer for showing you how you can do it